# Disabling Fullscreen X Button

Tags: google-chrome

When in Chrome Fullscreen mode if you bring your cursor to the top center, an **X** button that looks like this [image] appears in flying style.

I've been able to disable this feature in past versions with the flag `#simplified-fullscreen-ui` ([Reference](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/yUbhOUJuJaY/jmpkQ64cBAAJ)). However, I no longer see this flag listed and the feature is enabled again (`73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)`). **Was this flag removed, or renamed? either way, I just want a solution to turn it off.**

This is causing annoying behavior when playing any game in (F11) Fullscreen mode. Tested on `73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)`